# Python AWS Lambda Url invokes twice

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I seem to have a problem with my lambda function. My function invokes only once when I test it on AWS. However, when I invoke the lambda function through the function URL it executes twice! Has anyone experienced this before?

```
import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
ddbClient = boto3.client('dynamodb')

def LatestDBrow():
...
    return row


#Invoke lambda function
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    scratchPadlist = []
    scratchPadlist = LatestDBrow()
    
    #print(scratchPadlist)
    
    #Put TS row into variables
    inBatchTrial = scratchPadlist[0]
    inNoOfUsersProcessed = scratchPadlist[1]
    inl1Alpha = scratchPadlist[2]
    inl1Beta = scratchPadlist[3]
    
    
    #Update wanted values
    inBatchTrial += 1
    inl1Alpha = 1
    inl1Beta = 1
                                                     
    TableColNames = ['Batch Trial','No. of users processed','L1 Alpha',
                           'L1 Beta','L1 N','L1 Rewards',
                           'L1 Click Pct','L2 Alpha','L2 Beta',
                           'L2 N','L2 Rewards','L2 Click Pct',
                           'Next Page Shown']
                           
    TSlist =    [inBatchTrial, inNoOfUsersProcessed, inl1Alpha,
                    inl1Beta, inl1N, inl1Rewards,
                    inl1ClickPct, inl2Alpha, inl2Beta,
                    inl2N, inl2Rewards,inl2ClickPct,
                    innextPageShown]
    
    dbDict = {TableColNames[i]: str(TSlist[i]) for i in range(len(TableColNames))}

    table1 = dynamodb.Table("TestDB")
    table1.put_item(Item = dbDict)
```

Comment: How are you invoking function URL?

Comment: HTTPS GET request through web browser

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have same issue (but for a .Net Core lambda).

Comment: Please add some execution logs, how do you know its called twice?
Is it done each time or just on cold start?
Do you see two separate request with unique request ids, or its single request with unknown error in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

When you see multiple executions of a lambda, a common cause could be that the upstream caller hasn't received a response in a timely manner. If your function doesn't return the response quickly, it could make this worse.

When that happens, depending on the client used, the http request method may be retried. One thing to check on the client side are time out settings.